# POSTGRES Query: How do I return the average of a moving average in a PostGres database?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, database-design, sqlalchemy

I'm a bit new to PostGres so bear with me here. My table looks something like the following:

```
  ticker  |        datetime        |  open  |  high  |  low   | close  | volume 
----------+------------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------
 IJKLMNOP | 2014-12-31 21:46:00-06 | 959.93 | 959.93 | 959.93 | 959.93 | 0
 ABCDEFGH | 2014-12-31 21:47:00-06 | 959.93 |    960 | 958.65 | 958.65 | 40
 SYMPHONY | 2014-12-31 21:48:00-06 |    960 |    960 | 958.65 |    960 | 10
 ABCDEFGH | 2014-12-31 21:49:00-06 |    960 | 960.25 |    960 | 960.25 | 24
 IJKLMNOP | 2014-12-31 21:50:00-06 | 960.25 | 960.25 |    960 |    960 | 134
 ABCDEFGH | 2014-12-31 21:51:00-06 |  958.6 |    960 |  958.6 | 959.45 | 194
 SYMPHONY | 2014-12-31 21:52:00-06 | 959.45 | 960.43 | 959.45 |  960.4 | 30
 ABCDEFGH | 2014-12-31 21:53:00-06 |  960.4 | 961.43 |  960.4 | 961.43 | 36
 IJKLMNOP | 2014-12-31 21:54:00-06 | 961.43 | 961.98 | 961.43 | 961.98 | 2
 ABCDEFGH | 2014-12-31 21:55:00-06 | 961.98 | 961.98 | 961.98 | 961.98 | 0
 SYMPHONY | 2014-12-31 21:56:00-06 | 961.98 | 961.98 | 961.98 | 961.98 | 0
 ABCDEFGH | 2014-12-31 21:57:00-06 | 961.98 | 961.98 | 961.98 | 961.98 | 0
 SYMPHONY | 2014-12-31 21:58:00-06 | 961.98 | 961.98 | 961.98 | 961.98 | 0
```

It contains historical data of multiple stocks. I want to calculate the moving average of a distinct ticker over a 2 hour period. Then I want to calculate the average and standard deviation of the moving average  for that ticker.

I want to do this for each distinct ticker, and then get back the ones that match a certain criteria.

So, in order:

1) Calculate (the 2 hour) moving average of each distinct ticker

2) Calculate the average and standard deviation of the 2 hour moving average for each distinct ticker

3) return the tickers that match a criteria that depend on the average and standard deviation of the moving average.

How would I write out this query? I'm really stuck and have no clue how to proceed.

I'm accessing the database through python using sqlAlchemy and Pandas

Comment: You're gonna want to use window functions. There's a nice tutorial on them here: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-window-function/

Comment: `avg(column) over (window), stddev(column) over (window)`. However, PostgreSQL does not support range-windows, only row-windows, so it can be a bit difficulty, and depending on the data you may have to join on `generate_series`.

Comment: How would I limit it to distinct tickers? All the tickers are in the same table, but I want to calculate the average and stuff for distinct tickers so I can query which ticker is relevant for me.

Comment: Ok, so just read up a bit more and that's using GROUP BY if I'm not wrong. What do you mean by range windows instead of row windows?

Comment: Indeed, the syntax **if** supported would be something like `select avg(value) over (order by timestamp range between '2 hour'::interval preceding and current row) from foo;` However as @CraigRinger noted, range windows are not supported, so you can window only by *n-number of *rows** right now :F

Comment: hence the trick of using `group by` and/or `generate_series` to create a range, join and aggregate on it, then use a row-range window on the result.

Comment: I'm sorry, a lot of this stuff is just blowing past me. Do you mind constructing what a sample query would look like? Doesn't have to complete the requirements of the question, just something that explains what each of the query commands you guys mention above does? I think you guys are combining multiple select statements?